# Polymorphic in AIDL inout param

Tags: android, aidl

for example, there are two classes

```
class B extends A { public int x; };
```

in AIDL:

```
public void func( inout A params ); // the function does not change B.x value
```

then there is the following code:

```
B objB;
objB.x = 99;
IObject.func( objB );
```

when the code exectued, objB.x will be changed( not 99 ) since the "func" function only returned the part A of objB, objB.x will get a default value( most are 0 ).

My question:

How to make objB.x be constant if "func" function does not change B.x value?

Comment: for constant u can declare it as static final

Comment: @mona but objB.x maybe changed in other situations. I just want it be constant in this scenario.

Comment: so in func only u dont wanna change B.x?

Comment: in func B.x will not be changed, i dont wanna change B.x in the caller of func

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying thing I have dealt with before. I presume both of your objects implement parcelable. The only solution I was ever able to find to this was simply to create a container object that was parcelable. Because both of your classes A and B are parcelable its a pretty easy object to create.

The reason this is happening I think is because the CREATOR that gets used is from the parameter type which is A. Its the reason I recommend against AIDL if possible but there are situations where it does make sense. Hope that helps.